# What is the meaning of &^ in go?

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

In the following piece of code, the output is 8 and therefore 1000 in binary.

Why is this the case?

```
a := 10
b: = 3

fmt.Println(a &^ b)
fmt.Printf("a &^ b: %b\n", uint64(a &^ b))
```

This is in golang. I have been told it is when the bits are both 0 it will output in 1, but this would result in 0100, which is 4.

Comment: It is "bit clear (**AND NOT**)" https://go.dev/ref/spec

Comment: `a &^ b` is literally `XOR` and `AND` i.e. `a & (^b)` in one operation: https://go.dev/play/p/plW5SDVWGW2